# EasyPHP and Windows 8 port 127.0.0.1 issue

Tags: windows, easyphp

I  just installed EasyPHP on my Win8 laptop and I cant open EasyPHP Administration.

I check some solution on net but without success. I tried to update  httpd.config from 127.0.0.1:80 to 127.0.0.1:8080  and 127.0.0.1:8001 and then nothing.

When I installed I could open local web with content of www folder.

What is the solution of this issue ? how to run administration tab in EasyPHP ?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and what you need to do is run easyPHP as an administrator. Since you are running windows 8 here is how.

**Step 1:** On your Tile Screen find easyPHP
**Step 2:** Right click on it and a menu bar will popup below.
**Step 3:** Select "Run as Administrator"

This should get it up, let me know if it doesn't.

Good Luck.

Comment: have any way without Run as Administrator ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. May have something to do with IPv6 being the default on Windows 8.

In the end, I installed XAMPP instead, this appears to just work. That installation does have a minor difference in the apache .conf file:
Listen 80
instead of Listen 127.0.0.1:80

I don't think this is the full solution for EasyPHP though, as I tried that change.

Answer (score 0):

Tried stuff above, no luck.  Bottom line:

- Could not get it work in IE10, Metro or desktop version of the
     browser.

  Got to 127.0.0.1 in Chrome and Firefox (This is Local Web)

  From Local Web I can click on the home icon and get to Administration

  Works Run as Administrator or not

I do need to add, it ain't going to win any performance issues